# Access this.functionName() into another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function I can access like : `this.randomNumber()` which output a random number like : `54851247`

The goal of the question is to access this function into another function.

```
console.log(this.randomNumber()); // Output: 54851247
function anotherFunction() {
    console.log(this.randomNumber()); // Error
}
```

Error I get :

> Uncaught TypeError: this.createTorrentId is not a function

Full code :

```
Ext.ns("Deluge.add");
Deluge.add.FileWindow = Ext.extend(Deluge.add.Window, {
    title: _("Add from File"),
    layout: "fit",
    width: 350,
    height: 115,
    modal: !0,
    plain: !0,
    buttonAlign: "center",
    closeAction: "hide",
    bodyStyle: "padding: 10px 5px;",
    iconCls: "x-deluge-add-file",
    initComponent: function() {
        Deluge.add.FileWindow.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
        this.addButton(_("Add"), this.onAddClick, this);
        this.form = this.add({
            xtype: "form",
            baseCls: "x-plain",
            labelWidth: 35,
            autoHeight: !0,
            fileUpload: !0,
            items: [{
                xtype: "fileuploadfield",
                name: "file",
                buttonCfg: {
                    text: _("Browse") + "..."
                }
            }]
        })
    },
    onAddClick: function(c, b) {
        console.log(this.randomNumber()); // Output: 54851247
        function anotherFunction() {
            console.log(this.randomNumber()); // Error
        }
    },
})
```

Declaration of the function:

```
Ext.ns("Deluge.add");
Deluge.add.Window = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
    initComponent: function() {
        Deluge.add.Window.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
        this.addEvents("beforeadd", "add", "addfailed")
    },
    randomNumber: function() {
        return new Date().getTime()
    }
});
```

Comment: Whats you issue?

Comment: are you using es6?

Comment: Can you maybe post the whole code ? Where do your function randomNumber live ? Inside a class ? Where do you call your other function anotherFunction ? Inside the same class ?

Comment: you can save the scope into another variable then you can use it as per your wish. i have modified  your code . check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ypdnzmx7/

Comment: @RAGINROSE working great!

Answer (score 1):

Return that from function from another function

```js
function a(){console.log("ds")}
function b(){return a();}
b();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the current scope which in this case is changed. Basically it means that the `randomNumber()` should exist on all objects in order to be able to do

```
this.randomNumber();
```

I suggest you add this function to the global/window scope so than you can simply say

```
randomNumber();
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know how this function is actually declared

Comment: Well, have you written it or what? Where do you manage to call it successfuly?

Comment: No I didn't written it. I will add the full code on how I call it